# Logistic Regression (encapsulating chronology within features)

Tags: time-series, logistic, feature-engineering

I am looking for suggestions on **how I might construct features that would encapsulate the timings/order of events** (ultimately, to be used to predict a future event)

**Background**

I have timestamped interactions between customers and a business:

```
Customer  Date    Code   Interaction
------------------------------------------------
Donald    1 Jan   A      letter sent: change of T&Cs
Donald    2 Jan   B      letter sent: notification of fine
Donald    3 Jan   C      customer pays fine
Donald    4 Jan  *Y     *customer files complaint (about fine)
------------------------------------------------
Theresa   1 Jan   D      customer applies for product
Theresa   2 Jan   E      application rejected
Theresa   3 Jan   F      customer files complaint (about rejection)
------------------------------------------------
Angela    1 Jan   B      letter sent: notification of fine
Angela    2 Jan   D      customer applies for product
Angela    3 Jan   E      application rejected
Angela    4 Jan  *Y     *customer files complaint (about fine)
```

I would like to use this data to predict how likely Y will occur within some timeframe, given what has occured up until now.

If I use the shopping basket analogy, the logistic regression model can be used to predict if *item Y* will be in the *basket* given that *item A* is present, or if *item B* is present, etc. In my context, it can be used to predict if a *complaint (about fine)* will happen in a *customer jounrey* given that *interaction A* has occured, or if *interaction B* has occured, etc.

However, with a customer journey, the **combination** of events (and even the **order** in which they happen) are likely more important than the individual events themselves.

**Question**

What new features can I generate that would encapsulate the chronological order of customer-business interactions?

**Current solution**

My convoluted solution is to one-hot encode each customer journey:

- Does A occur? `A`
- Does B occur? `B`
- Does A happen at any point after B? `A>B`
- Does B happen at any point after A? `B>A`
- etc.

and then use **logistic regression**.

```
Customer | A   B   C   A>B  B>A  A>C  C>A  B>C  C>B  A>B>C | Y
---------+-------------------------------------------------+----
Donald   | x   x   x   x         x         x         x     | 1
Theresa  |                                                 | 0
Angela   |     x                                           | 1
```

**Does my solution sound sensible? Are there any better suggestions?**

Bonus points if there's a suggestion that encapsulates the time elapsed between subsequent events.

Comment: +1 for the question. Can it be assumed that you have relatively low number of possible events and rather big dataset?

Comment: @Tim - with the data in its current form, the number of possible events is very large. I aim to group/categorise events to reduce the total number while not making it too generic (but this would be a separate exercise). Given that there are a large number of events, the event of interest itself (complaint) is rare, and so this is quite an imbalanced data set.